# How Can I Correct Weird Spacing Behavior in Bootstrap Tabular Forms?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason my table has way too much spacing. There is something that is causing the padding to be off, but I'm not sure where it is. Almost all of the CSS is the basic Bootstrap code for tables.

[image]

### **HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Team</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <th>9</th>
                    <th>10</th>
                    <th>11</th>
                    <th>12</th>
                    <th>R</th>
                    <th>H</th>
                    <th>E</th>
                    <th>Record</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>V</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control team-wide" type="text"  name="name" id="name"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning1" id="inning1"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning2" id="inning2"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning3" id="inning3"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning4" id="inning4"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning5" id="inning5"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning6" id="inning6"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning7" id="inning7"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning8" id="inning8"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning9" id="inning9"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning10" id="inning10"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning11" id="inning11"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="inning12" id="inning12"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="R" id="R"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="H" id="H"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="E" id="E"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control inning-wide" type="text"  name="Record" id="Record"></td>

                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                    <td>Table cell</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
        </div><!-- /.table-responsive -->  
    </div>
```

### **CSS**

```
.team-wide {
width: 80px;
margin-left: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 2000px) { /*scrollable inside my container*/
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap `.table` cells have 8px padding all around by default, you can override this with your own rule.

```
.table>thead>tr>th, 
.table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table>thead>tr>td, 
.table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table>tfoot>tr>td {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Also, it will look alot better if you align the header text to the center...

```
.table>thead>tr>th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Ah I thought I looked all around for that padding... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap documentation has a solution:

Condensed table
Add .table-condensed to make tables more compact by cutting cell padding in half.

Change the table tag to

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
```

See the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)

Comment: Thanks for that. It actually doesn't apply to this situation because I made the entire form horizontally scroll, but it is nice to know for future references.